# Rails carrierwave has_many error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Each User has_one Character. Each Character has_one :profilepicture, of class Picturething, which holds a Carrierwave mount_uploader to upload a singe picture. Each Character has_many :standardpictures, also of class Picturething. Picture upload is handled in views/users/edit, which hits the update_pictures method in users_controller.

The idea is to upload one standardpicture at a time. It seems to work, Rails console > Picturething.all shows that a new Picturething has been added to the database, and it is correctly displayed on the page. This is intended to be one of the character.standardpictures.

The weird thing is, somehow in this whole process, the character's :profilepicture is also set to be the same picture that was uploaded. I don't understand how this is happening. At no point do I have code saying something like "@character.profilepicture = standardpicture", but somehow it has decided that both the first :standardpicture and the :profilepicture are one and the same. If the profilepicture exists, which it shouldn't yet, it is displayed on the edit.html.erb page, where I have the line `<% if @character.profilepicture.nil? %>`. It displays the uploaded picture here, so clearly profilepicture is not nil, but it should be.

How is this happening?

character.rb:

```
has_many :standardpictures, class_name: "Picturething", dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :standardpictures
has_one  :profilepicture, class_name: "Picturething", dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profilepicture
```

picturething.rb:

```
class Picturething < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to      :character
  mount_uploader  :picture, CharacterpicUploader
  validate        :picture_size
end
```

app/views/users/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :standardpicture, url: update_pictures_user_path, 
             method: :post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :picture %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload pictures", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
post '/users/:callsign/update_pictures', to: 'users#update_pictures',  as: :update_pictures_user
```

users_controller.rb:

```
def update_pictures
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  @user = @character.sociable
  @standardpicture = @character.standardpictures.build(update_pictures_user_params)
  if @standardpicture.save
    flash[:success] = "Pictures updated"
    redirect_to(edit_user_path(@user))
  else
    redirect_to(edit_user_path(@user))
  end
end # update_pictures

def update_pictures_user_params
  params.require(:standardpicture).permit(:picture)
end
```

Back to app/views/users/edit.html.erb:

```
<% if @character.profilepicture.nil? %>
  <p>Select a picture below to use as your profile picture</p>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag @character.profilepicture.picture %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The relationship between character.rb and picturething.rb was not fully specified. This fixes it:

character.rb:

```
has_many :standardpictures, class_name: "Picturething",
                            inverse_of: :character,
                            foreign_key: "character_standard_id",
                            dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :standardpictures

has_one  :profilepicture,   class_name: "Picturething",
                            inverse_of: :character,
                            foreign_key: "character_profile_id",
                            dependent: :destroy
```

picturething.rb:

```
belongs_to      :character, class_name: "Character",
                            inverse_of: :standardpictures,
                            foreign_key: :character_standard_id
belongs_to      :character, class_name: "Character",
                            inverse_of: :profilepicture,
                            foreign_key: :character_profile_id
```

Plus the migration to add :character_standard_id and :character_profile_id for Picturething in the database.

The interesting thing is that Picturething now requires two columns, :character_standard_id and :character_profile_id, but each column will only ever contain the same value. The second column seems redundant. I tried to get it working with just a single column, but couldn't. Whether this was due to it being impossible or due to my incompetence is not clear (I suspect the latter), but it would be good to know: Can this problem be solved with a single id column in the Picturething database?